# How to send text to invisible input field

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate file uploading.

Here is a `HTML` code for path-to-file input field and button for manual uploading:

```
<div class="ctrl_div">
     <input id="fileupload" class="hid" name="files" accept="application/zip" data-url="/Server/file/upload" type="file">
     <button id="fileBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Upload</button>
</div>
```

When I try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="fileupload"]').send_keys(path_to_file)
```

I get `ElementNotVisibleException`

I also tried

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('fileupload').style.visibility = 'visible';")
```

But input field remains invisible for `webdriver`.

Any ideas?

P.S. Adding implicit/explicit wait will not make a trick

Comment: if you want to click on browse button use this xpath : .//*[@id='fileupload'] for upload button xpath is:.//*[@id='fileBtn']

Comment: do you have any other element which is same as <input id="fileupload" on your HTML DOM

Comment: You should try with `driver.execute_script(document.getElementById('fileUpload').style.display='block';");`

Comment: @sameerjoshi, no. Button was not the target element

Comment: @fabersky , yeah, it seems to work. thanks. You can delete your comment and provide it as answer, so I can accept it

Comment: @Andersson done! I'm glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with

```
driver.execute_script(document.getElementById('fileUpload').style.display='bloc‌​k';");
```