# Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command

Tags: selenium, webdriver

This is popup in my project, I am facing problem with click on"I'm ready to return to the registration home page"link of it.
        I'm locating by id

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id*='ProgramWizardBase_ctl00_HomePageHyperLink']")).click();
```

It throws error "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with element"][1]
        [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbjJb.png

Comment: is you element really visible? if it's not, maybe you should try something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/35649658/1033737

Comment: you can check it by isVisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All, Actually the element was invisible so i tried like this -

```
element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id*='ProgramWizardBase_ctl00_HomePageHyperL‌​ink']"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

and its working..

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='ProgramWizardBase_ctl00_HomePageHyperLink']")).click());
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com) accepts **code-only answer** like this, but it isn't *very* help for others. Please [edit] your answer and explain *How does your code work*. Sometimes, also *Why doesn't OP's code work*.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to move to alert like:

```
 driver.switchTo().alert();
```

and then try to perform action (assuming you are finding element correctly):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id*='ProgramWizardBase_ctl00_HomePageHyperLink']")).click();
```